can someone display steps for initial create cvs and commit first file
I have set up cvs on my home machine with the cvsroot of /home/slw/cvs/CVSROOT. So far easy to do. Now the next first action is to commit a file. Correct? I am erroring out with any commit command.
:: export CVSROOT=/home/slw/cvs
:: cvs commit -r 1.0.0.1 -m "Initial commit" -R
cvs commit: in directory .:
cvs [commit aborted]: there is no version here; run 'cvs checkout' first

:: cvs checkout /home/slw/shermFiles/perl/ffmpegFiles/readInFilesToUseFfmpeg
cvs [checkout aborted]: Absolute module reference invalid: `/home/slw/shermFiles/perl/ffmpegFiles/readInFilesToUseFfmpeg'

:: cvs commit -m "Initial commit" -R
cvs commit: in directory .:
cvs [commit aborted]: there is no version here; run 'cvs checkout' first

:: cvs commit -m "Initial commit" readInFilesToUseFfmpeg
cvs commit: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs commit: nothing known about `readInFilesToUseFfmpeg'
cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!

:: cvs commit -m "Initial commit" ./readInFilesToUseFfmpeg
cvs commit: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs commit: nothing known about `readInFilesToUseFfmpeg'
cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!


Try checking the man cvs documentation.  I use rcs myself, and first check in comment is the file descriptor.
